# Attribute Error: 'Window' has no object 'nameE'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Can someone explain what it means by `AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'nameE'`. I've been modifying my code for the past hour trying to find a solution but have been unsuccessful. I think it has something to do with the class 'Window' but I am unsure what it is. I would be grateful if someone could scan through the code quickly to see if they can find why the error is present. Thank you.

**Here's my code:**

```
from tkinter import *


class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        root.title("Sign Up or Login")
        root.minsize(width=300, height=300)
        root.maxsize(width=300,height=300)

        self.login_button = Button(master, text = "Login", width=18,height=4, command=self.LoginPage)
        self.signup_button = Button(master, text = "Sign Up", width=18,height=4, command=self.SignupPage)

        self.login_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
        self.signup_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)

    def LoginPage(self):

        root.title("Login")
        self.login_button.place_forget()
        self.signup_button.place_forget()

        self.text_username = Label(root, text = "Username : ")
        self.text_password = Label(root, text = "Password : ")

        self.usernameE = Entry(root)
        self.passwordE = Entry(root)

        self.text_username.place(relx=0.3, rely= 0.4, anchor=CENTER)
        self.text_password.place(relx=0.3, rely= 0.6, anchor=CENTER)

        self.usernameE.place(relx=0.65,rely= 0.4, anchor=CENTER)
        self.passwordE.place(relx=0.65,rely= 0.6, anchor=CENTER)

        self.submit_button_login = Button(root, text="Submit", command=self.SubmitInfo)
        self.submit_button_login.place(relx=0.7,rely=0.7)



    def SignupPage(self):

        root.title("Sign Up")
        self.login_button.place_forget()
        self.signup_button.place_forget()

        self.text_name = Label(root, text = "Name :")
        self.text_age = Label(root, text = "Age :")
        self.text_username = Label(root, text = "Username :")
        self.text_password = Label(root, text = "Password :")

        self.text_name.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
        self.text_age.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.4, anchor=CENTER)
        self.text_username.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.6,anchor=CENTER)
        self.text_password.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.8,anchor=CENTER)

        self.nameE = Entry(root)
        self.ageE = Entry(root)
        self.usernameE2 = Entry(root)
        self.passwordE2 = Entry(root)

        self.nameE.place(relx= 0.4, rely=0.2)
        self.ageE.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.4)
        self.usernameE2.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.6)
        self.passwordE2.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.8)

        self.submit_button_signup = Button(root, text="Submit", command=self.SubmitInfo)
        self.submit_button_signup.place(relx= 0.7, rely=0.9)

    def SubmitInfo(self):

        self.username_login = self.usernameE.get()
        self.password_login = self.passwordE.get()
        self.name_signup = self.nameE.get()
        self.age_signup = self.ageE.get()
        self.username_signup = self.usernameE2.get()
        self.password_signup = self.passwordE2.get()
        print(self.username_login)


root = Tk()

run = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Presumably you're calling SubmitInfo before the object has been given a nameE by SignupPage?

Comment: Denziloe Thanks for highlighting the issue. I have now created two separate functions

Comment: Don't use `root` inside your class, that's the name of the `Tk()` object *outside the class*. You pass `root` to the class on initialization and save it as `self.master`, so use that inside the class.

Comment: fhdrsdg Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same `SubmitInfo` function, which calls all of the entries, but only some of the entries are being created by selecting either `SignupPage` or `LoginPage`

Declaring them at the creation of the class is one workaround for this:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        root.title("Sign Up or Login")
        root.minsize(width=300, height=300)
        root.maxsize(width=300,height=300)

        self.login_button = Button(master, text = "Login", width=18,height=4, command=self.LoginPage)
        self.signup_button = Button(master, text = "Sign Up", width=18,height=4, command=self.SignupPage)

        self.login_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
        self.signup_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)

        self.usernameE = Entry(root)
        self.passwordE = Entry(root)

        self.nameE = Entry(root)
        self.ageE = Entry(root)
        self.usernameE2 = Entry(root)
        self.passwordE2 = Entry(root)

    def LoginPage(self):

        root.title("Login")
        self.login_button.place_forget()
        self.signup_button.place_forget()

        self.text_username = Label(root, text = "Username : ")
        self.text_password = Label(root, text = "Password : ")

        self.text_username.place(relx=0.3, rely= 0.4, anchor=CENTER)
        self.text_password.place(relx=0.3, rely= 0.6, anchor=CENTER)

        self.usernameE.place(relx=0.65,rely= 0.4, anchor=CENTER)
        self.passwordE.place(relx=0.65,rely= 0.6, anchor=CENTER)

        self.submit_button_login = Button(root, text="Submit", command=self.SubmitInfo)
        self.submit_button_login.place(relx=0.7,rely=0.7)

    def SignupPage(self):

        root.title("Sign Up")
        self.login_button.place_forget()
        self.signup_button.place_forget()

        self.text_name = Label(root, text = "Name :")
        self.text_age = Label(root, text = "Age :")
        self.text_username = Label(root, text = "Username :")
        self.text_password = Label(root, text = "Password :")

        self.text_name.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
        self.text_age.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.4, anchor=CENTER)
        self.text_username.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.6,anchor=CENTER)
        self.text_password.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.8,anchor=CENTER)

        self.nameE.place(relx= 0.4, rely=0.2)
        self.ageE.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.4)
        self.usernameE2.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.6)
        self.passwordE2.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.8)

        self.submit_button_signup = Button(root, text="Submit", command=self.SubmitInfo)
        self.submit_button_signup.place(relx= 0.7, rely=0.9)

    def SubmitInfo(self):

        self.username_login = self.usernameE.get()
        self.password_login = self.passwordE.get()
        self.name_signup = self.nameE.get()
        self.age_signup = self.ageE.get()
        self.username_signup = self.usernameE2.get()
        self.password_signup = self.passwordE2.get()
        print(self.username_login)


root = Tk()

run = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```